# Appending an input file with awk after a pattern (looping?)

Tags: awk

I am trying to take a text file called 'input', of the form

```
line1 
line2
line3
PATTERN
x y z
x y z
lineN
```

and use awk to place a number (1) after each "x y z" line. I need the lines before the PATTERN and after the "x y z' lines (lineN) in the output. The output I needs looks like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
PATTERN
x y z   1 
x y z   1
lineN
```

What I have so far is:

```
awk '/PATTERN/ {getline; print $0 "   1" }' < input > output
```

This gives:

```
x y z   1
```

Is it possible to set up a loop to get awk to append an arbitrary number of "x y z" lines or stop after the "x y z" type lines finish?

Comment: I edited to look more file like. do you need remplacement after PATTERN (and x y z might be 1 2 3 or foo what ever) or editing only line with x y z ?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to represent it in the fashion you have changed it to. Yes replacement after the PATTERN is found. x y z are just three columns only the lines with x y z should be appended if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The looping can help:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{print;getline;while(!/lineN/){$(NF+1)="  1";print;getline}}1'
```

Or to extend [@Janis idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188116/89144):

```
awk '/lineN/{f=0}f{$(NF+1)="  1"}/PATTERN/{f=1}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that only the literal "x y z" lines after PATTERN shall be replaced.

```
awk '
  /PATTERN/ { f=1 }
  f && /x y z/ { print $0, 1 ; next }
  { print }
'
```

If it's lines with three arbitrary fields then use

```
awk '
  /PATTERN/ { f=1 }
  f && NF==3 { print $0, 1 ; next }
  { print }
'
```

Comment: If OP wants to print lines after `PATTERN` and before `lineN` (as one block) you have to add `f=0` after block finish.

Comment: Costas, the OP's sample as presented did not suggest that lineN is a pattern like "PATTERN" that terminates a block; as described it's just a continuation of the data line1, line2, ..., lineN, or so it seems at least.

Comment: `lineN` can have 3 fields too... In any way OP should some how indicate difference between `x y z` and `lineN` to fix position where script should stop to add `1`

Comment: Indeed the actual requirements would need clarification. I'm sure the OP will come back to ask if necessary once he switches from his sample data to the real data.